# Imports using PyCharm don't work on command line

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I'm a bit new to Python and I'm building a project in PyCharm since I'm used to IntelliJ, and have a problem with my file structure. When I need to import a file in the same subdirectory-- directory `c`, I have to type

`from a.b.c import y` where `a` is the project's home directory `b.c` is the sub directory I'm in.

So I'm not able to `import y` directory. Which this then causes a problem if I want to run this file via command line, it uses the current directory as the path, meaning the import doesn't know anything about `x.xx`. What can I do to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of this answer I'm assuming `y` is a Python module in the `c` directory. In other words there is a file called `y.py` in `a/b/c`.

`import y` works in a Python module in directory `c` if the current working directory is also `c`.

In Intellij IDEA with the Python plugin (much the same as PyCharm most of the time) the current working directory is called the "Working Directory" in each Run/Debug configuration you set up to run your script.

`import y` will also work if `c` is on the `PYTHONPATH`.

The other way to make `y` available to the import statement is to turn `a` and `b` directories into Python packages. That means at least putting an empty `__init__.py` file in both the `a` and `b` directories.

You can then use `a` as the root directory for the project, and use:

```
from a.b.c import y
```

It's worth reading [The Definitive Guide to Python import Statements](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html) if you're not sure how Python resolves imports.

Comment: I just modify sys.path because it’s easy and can be different for different programs.